# confuse create print out when create some condition in Sqlite3 with python

Tags: python, database, sqlite, conditional-statements, split

I created a test database with the table name and in it there are two columns with names Words and Sentences and I want to do a search in databases (sqlite3) whether the data or the word is there or not, if there is then the system will output / print from table sentence . I was confused at this section. and I tried to make this code but it does not appear the results I wanted.

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys

connection = lite.connect('test.db')
with con:
  cur = con.cursore()
  cur execute("Select words From test")
  inpt = "what the meaning of python ?"
  for word in stn.split():
    if word in words:
      print Sentence
```

I break a sentence into a few words, then do a search in a database, word in the variable inpt is in the column the words or not, if there is then the system will print the column sentence.

I created a database like this:

```
words         Sentences
----------    -------------------
Python        Python is a program language
Django        web framework for python
```

Comment: what is words? it's undefined.

Comment: yap, that's the output what i get. The "words" undefined

Comment: Then you have to define it. also stn is undefined.

Comment: but the "words" is exist in the database

Comment: what is the expect output with above database?

Comment: I expect the output of the column "sentence", so if the "word" is found in databases column "Words" then print a "sentence"

Comment: from where the "word" come? by splitting Sentences from database or by spliting the inpt from the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
import sqlite3 as lite

con = lite.connect('test.db')
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    for row in cur.execute("Select words, Sentences From test"):
        inpt = "what the meaning of Python ?"
        if row[0] in inpt:
            print row[1]
```

Output:

```
Python is a program language
```